# Send message from php/mysql to iPhones

Tags: ios, firebase, reminders, apn

i am building a website which needs to send *reminder* messages to iOS (and Android) devices at certain times/dates. **So not to a specific app on an iPhone, but to the iPhone itself.**

like in the way the reminders app on the iPhone works: even when the app isn't active, reminders pop up.

For the last two days i've been googling on-and-off and reading about apns and firebase etc., but every script and tutorial understandably mentions tokens and id's that you need to receive from Apple and/or Android to get it to work.

One thing i can't find on google is: do i need to have an developer ID or something for this? I'm no xcode or swift programmer, i mainly work with php and query etc. and hopefully can avoid paying yearly for a developer license with Apple or Google.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction?

And surely any pointers to a good service or script to use is also very helpful. In the mean time i'll keep digging.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can't send a message to the phone itself (unless you want to send a text message to the mobile/cellular number).  You can only send a notification by having an app on the phone that has provided a push token to your server; this token is unique to your app installation on that phone.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So i do need to build an iPhone app to be able to do this... i hoped that i didn't need to. ok then i'll have to think things over.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to run your app on an actual device you need to be registered developer, to be able to create certificates and provisioning profiles to sign your app with. You also need to be able to create certificates to be able to send push notifications.

You write that you want to send notifications directly to the phone. This isn't possible. All push notifications must be sent to an app. It doesn't matter if the app is running or not. Which makes sense. Otherwise you would be able to send push notifications to any iOS device out there...

Comment: I hoped that Apple handled the messages in a way that their apn doesn't send messages to an app but to the phone itself (they know the iPhone). but as i read your comment (and the one above yours), i always do need to have an app on the device itself to send messages to....that's not what i hoped to hear....

seems that webapps still have a way to go to be able to provide things like that i am asking about. too bad :-(

Comment: Technically, the notification IS sent to the device itself, but it's then handled by the app the notification belongs to. I don't see how you would be able to know which device you should send the notification to if there isn't an app on the device. What kind of notifications are you trying to send? I.e. what are they for?

Comment: i understand. They are reminders to do stuff, much like apple's own reminders app. So at a certain time/date the user gets a notification on their screen to do something.

Comment: And how will you now which device to send the notification to? And what to send? Do you have a website where to do items/reminders are created?

Comment: Yes, the website is php/html/jquery/mysql in essence and i was hoping to send push notifications like a lot of sites these days do. When i use safari and go to 9to5mac.com for instance, the user gets asked if it's ok that the particular site send notifications. Say yes once and from then on you'll regularly receive messages. The site doesn't know who i am. In my particular case my site has to know who to send the message to, thats why i read apns would tackle that for me as i need keys and id's. Once i read i needed an app on the device for it, i wanted to know for sure, hence why i asked here

Comment: To send web notifications to macOS you still need a paid Apple developer membership to generate a push certificate.